# make: Nothing to be done for 'all'. in Omnet

Tags: makefile, omnet++

After Installng Omnetpp 5.5.1 in Ubuntu 18.04 ,For any folder in Omnetpp, make command is not making any sense.
As it showing the following message:

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Even suggested methods on Internet are not working in my case.Please help.
My makefile is following for Aloha Folder.

```
#
# OMNeT++/OMNEST Makefile for aloha
#
# This file was generated with the command:
#  opp_makemake -f --deep
#

# Name of target to be created (-o option)
TARGET = aloha$(D)$(EXE_SUFFIX)
TARGET_DIR = .

# User interface (uncomment one) (-u option)
USERIF_LIBS = $(ALL_ENV_LIBS) # that is, $(TKENV_LIBS) $(QTENV_LIBS) $(CMDENV_LIBS)
#USERIF_LIBS = $(CMDENV_LIBS)
#USERIF_LIBS = $(TKENV_LIBS)
#USERIF_LIBS = $(QTENV_LIBS)

# C++ include paths (with -I)
INCLUDE_PATH =

# Additional object and library files to link with
EXTRA_OBJS =

# Additional libraries (-L, -l options)
LIBS =

# Output directory
PROJECT_OUTPUT_DIR = out
PROJECTRELATIVE_PATH =
O = $(PROJECT_OUTPUT_DIR)/$(CONFIGNAME)/$(PROJECTRELATIVE_PATH)

# Object files for local .cc, .msg and .sm files
OBJS = $O/Host.o $O/Server.o

# Message files
MSGFILES =

# SM files
SMFILES =

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Pull in OMNeT++ configuration (Makefile.inc)

ifneq ("$(OMNETPP_CONFIGFILE)","")
CONFIGFILE = $(OMNETPP_CONFIGFILE)
else
ifneq ("$(OMNETPP_ROOT)","")
CONFIGFILE = $(OMNETPP_ROOT)/Makefile.inc
else
CONFIGFILE = $(shell opp_configfilepath)
endif
endif

ifeq ("$(wildcard $(CONFIGFILE))","")
$(error Config file '$(CONFIGFILE)' does not exist -- add the OMNeT++ bin directory to the path so that opp_configfilepath can be found, or set the OMNETPP_CONFIGFILE variable to point to Makefile.inc)
endif

include $(CONFIGFILE)

# Simulation kernel and user interface libraries
OMNETPP_LIBS = $(OPPMAIN_LIB) $(USERIF_LIBS) $(KERNEL_LIBS) $(SYS_LIBS)

COPTS = $(CFLAGS) $(IMPORT_DEFINES)  $(INCLUDE_PATH) -I$(OMNETPP_INCL_DIR)
MSGCOPTS = $(INCLUDE_PATH)
SMCOPTS =

# we want to recompile everything if COPTS changes,
# so we store COPTS into $COPTS_FILE and have object
# files depend on it (except when "make depend" was called)
COPTS_FILE = $O/.last-copts
ifneq ("$(COPTS)","$(shell cat $(COPTS_FILE) 2>/dev/null || echo '')")
$(shell $(MKPATH) "$O" && echo "$(COPTS)" >$(COPTS_FILE))
endif

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# User-supplied makefile fragment(s)
# >>>
# <<<
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Main target
all: $(TARGET_DIR)/$(TARGET)

$(TARGET_DIR)/% :: $O/%
    @mkdir -p $(TARGET_DIR)
    $(Q)$(LN) $< $@
ifeq ($(TOOLCHAIN_NAME),clangc2)
    $(Q)-$(LN) $(<:%.dll=%.lib) $(@:%.dll=%.lib)
endif

$O/$(TARGET): $(OBJS)  $(wildcard $(EXTRA_OBJS)) Makefile $(CONFIGFILE)
    @$(MKPATH) $O
    @echo Creating executable: $@
    $(Q)$(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $O/$(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(EXTRA_OBJS) $(AS_NEEDED_OFF) $(WHOLE_ARCHIVE_ON) $(LIBS) $(WHOLE_ARCHIVE_OFF) $(OMNETPP_LIBS)

.PHONY: all clean cleanall depend msgheaders smheaders

.SUFFIXES: .cc

$O/%.o: %.cc $(COPTS_FILE) | msgheaders smheaders
    @$(MKPATH) $(dir $@)
    $(qecho) "$<"
    $(Q)$(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(COPTS) -o $@ $<

%_m.cc %_m.h: %.msg
    $(qecho) MSGC: $<
    $(Q)$(MSGC) -s _m.cc -MD -MP -MF $O/$(basename $<)_m.h.d $(MSGCOPTS) $?

%_sm.cc %_sm.h: %.sm
    $(qecho) SMC: $<
    $(Q)$(SMC) -c++ -suffix cc $(SMCOPTS) $?

msgheaders: $(MSGFILES:.msg=_m.h)

smheaders: $(SMFILES:.sm=_sm.h)

clean:
    $(qecho) Cleaning $(TARGET)
    $(Q)-rm -rf $O
    $(Q)-rm -f $(TARGET_DIR)/$(TARGET)
    $(Q)-rm -f $(TARGET_DIR)/$(TARGET:%.dll=%.lib)
    $(Q)-rm -f $(call opp_rwildcard, . , *_m.cc *_m.h *_sm.cc *_sm.h)

cleanall:
    $(Q)$(MAKE) -s clean MODE=release
    $(Q)$(MAKE) -s clean MODE=debug
    $(Q)-rm -rf $(PROJECT_OUTPUT_DIR)

# include all dependencies
-include $(OBJS:%=%.d) $(MSGFILES:%.msg=$O/%_m.h.d)
```

This aforementioned file is missing some information like  c++ INCLUDE_PATH and EXTRA_OBJS and LIBS.Is this the reason for not being run?Please Help.

Comment: This is a complex makefile so it's hard to see what's happening.  That message from make means that as far as make can tell, everything is up to date. I assume that is not actually the case?  Does the file `./aloha` exist?  Do the object files exist?  I recommend you run `make -d` (redirect the output, there will be a lot) and look through it to see what make is doing and why it's deciding to not rebuild anything.

Comment: @MadScientist , ./aloha exists but when graphical output seems visible ,there pops out a window which says unknown log format  character '<' .What should i do to resolve this log format exception.

Comment: That's a totally different question, it appears.  Your question is "why does make report "Nothing to be done"".... is that question answered?  If so this question is done and should be closed.  If you have some other question (it doesn't sound to me like your command above has any relationship to make, builds, or makefiles but I can't really tell: I don't know what _but when graphical output seems visible_ means... you mean when you run the `./aloha` program, what it prints out?) then you should open a new question with appropriate info and tags.

Comment: As for the other issue: I have answered that in your other separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The makefile says that 'Nothing to be done' because the executable is present and up to date, so it is indeed nothing to be done. This is not an error.

As you have indicated, you can execute `./aloha` and then that throws a runtime error. This is NOT related to the build process.